# Gulp tasks not showing on Netbeans 8.1 Mac OS

Tags: node.js, macos, gulp, netbeans-8.1

On our Mac OS machines we installed node.js and gulp.

On Netbeans 8.1 we set up the gulp path to: /usr/local/bin/gulp

The node.js path is set to: /usr/local/bin/node

We have a gulpfile.js in the project.

The default task is working. Clicking on Advanced and adding an existing task in that window, the task is running without any error.

After that the task appears under the Gulp Tasks list if you right click on the gulpfile.js.

But Netbeans does not automatically update the list. Also Reload Tasks have no effect.

The same thing under Ubuntu and Netbeans 8.1 is working fine out the box.

Anybody has this problem and solved it?

Besides that problem, how can the Gulp Tasks list be cleaned? Because it contains every Task or command one ever added using Advanced.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I work with Webstorm now...

Answer (score 2):

Try to `Help > Check for Updates`, it should have an update for the gulp and grunt.

It worked for me!